# Como criar uma Virtual String Tree no Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, treeview

O que acontece é que eu criei uma Virtual String Tree em Delphi (Typhon64), mas eu não sei como adicionar os nós pais e filhos para criar a árvore, olhei a documentação mas só achei eventos de clique que cria exclui e edita os nós(node), eu preciso criar essa árvore dinâmica até então eu consigo fazer isso só que usando evento de clique e adicionando os nós com método addChild(nil), mas não é isso que eu quero o que eu quero é que assim que carregar o formulário a Virtual String Tree já carregue com os nós(nodes)  e o nome dos nós e strings que eu definir, não importa se seja string ou um array de strings, desde que ele cria a árvore com os pais e os filhos eu sou muito grato pela ajuda!

até então a minha Virtual String Tree está como a imagem abaixo:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/xl9jwz.jpg

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de criar uma árvore como o exemplo abaixo, mas os valores eu irei definir:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/xgjx2u.jpg
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: poderia anexar as imagens na pergunta? não tenho acesso ao tinypic da empresa

Comment: Pronto a imagem acima seria o Virtual String Tree, preciso fazer uma Arvore com pais e filhos igual a da imagem abaixo, eu até consigo adicionar os elementos porém com evento de click, só que preciso fazer com que isso carregue a arvore quando abrir o formulario.

Comment: Não seria apenas colocar no evento onCreate no formulário o que você fez no evento de click?

Comment: list.AddChild(nil); // list é id do Virtual String Tree e AddChild é o metodo que adiciona o nó(node) que seria o elemento pai da arvore

Answer (score 0):

Para adicionar um nó pai declare uma variável do tipo `PVirtualNode`:

```
pai: PVirtualNode;
```

Dê um comando para iniciar a edição da grid antes de começar inserir os nós:

```
vstGrid.BeginUpdate;
```

Adicione o nó pai dessa forma:

```
pai := vstGrid.AddChild(nil, ["Conteúdo do nó"]);
```

Para adicionar os filhos passe o pai no primeiro parâmetro:

```
vstGrid.AddChild(pai, ["Conteúdo do nó"]);
```

Pra criar isso na abertura do formulário faça um laço no `OnShow` utilizando os comandos citados acima. Isso vai variar de acordo com a forma como você está trazendo essas informações.

Depois que terminar de inserir os nós dê um comando para finalizar a edição do grid:

```
vstGrid.EndUpdate;
```

Caso queira trazer os nós expandidos utilize o comando:

```
vstGrid.FullExpand;
```